# Pass config file as arg when calling snowsql from command line

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run a snowsql query from the command line and also to pass config file while calling snowsql. On [this](https://dwgeek.com/snowsql-command-line-options-and-examples.html/) blog there is an option presented:

```
–config PATH    SnowSQL config file path.
```

I tried including this:

```
#!/bin/bash

    snowsql -f training-data.sql \
      -o quiet=true \
      -o friendly=false \
      -o header=false \
      -config=./config
```

When I attempt ti run this I get:

> No connection could be found for onfig=./config

It's odd because previously, I could swear the error message was (Note onfig Vs. nfig!):

> No connection could be found for nfig=./config

How can I tell snowsql to use ./config as the config file when running the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need an equals sign. It should just be:

```
-config ./config
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work in that it progressed me to another error message :)
I'll open a new Q because I cannot see why, in cae it's of interest I now get `Problem with this option: nfig, err=not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`